# Warum heißt es "jungen Erwachsenen"?

Tags: meaning

> Luisa hatte zwei Gründe für die Firmengründung: jungen Erwachsenen eine gute Arbeitsstelle bieten und Müll sinnvoll verwenden

Ich verstehe nicht, warum "jungen Erwachsenen" so geschrieben wurde.

Ich meine, warum heißt es nicht "eine gute Arbeitsstelle für erwachsene Jungen bieten"?

Comment: Some comments to spelling mistakes: The beginning of sentences, names and nouns are capitalized in German. And there are no spaces before punctuation characters

Comment: It's literally _young grownups_ vs. _grown-up young ones_. In addition, _jungen_ (young, adj. pl.) !=Jungen (boys, pl. noun).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*junge Erwachsene* sind etwas anderes als *erwachsene Jungen* :-)

*junge Erwachsene* sind *young adults*, also Menschen, die erst seit Kurzem den Status "Erwachsener" erreicht haben. Das umfasst sowohl Mädchen als auch Jungen.

*erwachsene Jungen* sind *grown-up boys*, also Menschen, die man als Jungen kannte, die aber mittlerweile erwachsen geworden sind (oder aber erwachsene Männer, die sich verhalten wie Jungen). Hier geht es nur um Jungen, nicht um Mädchen.

> Luisa hatte zwei Gründe für die Firmengründung: jungen Erwachsenen eine gute Arbeitsstelle bieten und Müll sinnvoll verwenden

Dieser Satz bedeutet, dass Luisa jungen Menschen jeglichen Geschlechts die Möglichkeit einer guten Arbeitsstelle bietet.

Comment: warum heisst es (jeglichen Geschlechts) statt (jegliche Geschlecht) ?

Comment: Das ist Stoff für eine neue Frage ☺️ beziehe dich in der neuen Frage einfach auf diese Antwort.

Comment: ich hab das gemacht

Comment: Hallo Herr Dittmar. Wie ist die Pluralform von "Erwachsen"? Ich denke, dass " Erwachsenen" richtig ist, aber ein freund sag mir, dass die Pluralform ausnahmsweise " Erwachsene" ist.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have discussed why "junge Erwachsene" is not the same as "erwachsene Jungen", but there is another question worth discussing in your sentence:

It could have been written as "eine gute Arbeitsstelle für junge Erwachsene bieten", and would mean pretty much the same thing as the original. In German, there is a little bit more flexibility to rearrange sentence constituents than in English, and the order can subtly shift emphasis:

- "eine gute Arbeitsstelle für junge Erwachsene bieten" emphasizes the job.
- "jungen Erwachsenen eine gute Arbeitsstelle bieten" emphasizes the young adults.

Answer (score 2):

In Germany, the adjective that decribes a noun is always written in front of the noun. In this rare case you can switch the adjective and noun, because both words exist as adjective and noun. However, it changes the meaning of he sentence!

> die **j**ungen (*adjective*) **E**rwachsenen (*noun*) = the young adults
>
> die **e**rwachsenen (*adjective*) **J**ungen (*noun*) = the grown-up boys

Be aware that adjectives are written in small letters, whereas the nouns are capitalized!

Answer (score 1):

*junge Erwachsene* are young adults (either sex) while *erwachsene Jungen* are male only. Compare:

- *der Junge* (the boy)
- *jung* (young)