# Bedeutung von »jeglichen Geschlechts«

Tags: meaning

> Luisa hatte zwei Gründe für die Firmengründung: jungen Erwachsenen eine gute Arbeitsstelle bieten und Müll sinnvoll verwenden
>
> Dieser Satz bedeutet, dass Luisa jungen Menschen jeglichen Geschlechts die Möglichkeit einer guten Arbeitsstelle bietet.

Warum heisst es »jeglichen Geschlechts« statt »jegliche Geschlecht«?

Comment: Interessant ist ja auch, warum es nicht "beider Geschlechter" oder "beiderlei Geschlechts" heisst - Es gibt ja m.W. nicht mehr als zwei.

Comment: @tofro Das könnte mit der Frage zusammenhängen, was überhaupt der Zweck des zweiten Satzes ist und warum dort überhaupt vom Geschlecht die Rede ist - mangels Kontext müssen wir das offenlassen. Was die Anzahl angeht: [das ist ein weites Feld](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/gesellschaft/facebook-60-auswahlmoeglichkeiten-fuer-geschlecht-13135140.html)...

Comment: @tofro: Die SJWs, und nur die sind die Adressaten solcher Ausdrücke, sind da anderer Meinung.

Comment: @tofro Erstens scheint mir hier "jeglich" der neutrale Ausdruck zu sein, während "beider" eine ausdrückliche binäre Position bezieht. Zweitens könnte "beider Geschlechter" u.U. als Arbeitsplatzförderung für Hermaphroditen missverstanden werden.

Comment: 'jeglichen' geschlechts scheint mir hier sinnvoll, da es deutlicher macht, dass das Geschlecht hierbei irrelevant ist, womit an dieser Stelle auch die Frage der Limitierung irrelevant ist.

Comment: @Matthias Den Kontext findest du hier: http://german.stackexchange.com/a/33618/1224

Comment: Zur Erklärung: Es ging in der ursprünglichen, von EM1 auch verlinkten, Frage und meiner Antwort darauf um den Unterschied zwischen "jungen Erwachsenen" und "erwachsenen Jungen". Da es bei erwachsenen Jungen ausschließlich um männliche Personen geht, habe ich im Kontext des ursprünglichen Satzes klar gestellt, dass es dort aber um "junge Menschen jeglichen Geschlechts" geht. Manche Menschen unterscheiden auch heute nur zwischen "Penis oder nicht Penis", aber es gibt durchaus auch andere Wahrnehmungen (Stichwort: LGBT). Dem wollte ich mit der Formulierung "jeglichen Geschlechts" Rechnung tragen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vergleiche:

> Reisende **jeden Alters** besuchen das Museum.
>   Besucher **aller Hautfarben** waren schon hier.
>   Studierende **beiderlei Geschlechts** haben sich angemeldet.
>   Katzen **jeglicher Rassen** waren beim Wettbewerb vertreten.

Das was hier fett gedruckt ist, sind Beifügungen zu den unmittelbar davor stehenden Substantiven. Diese Beifügungen beschreiben die Substantive näher, und sie stehen im Genitiv, wie auch im folgenden Beispielen:

> Die Vorfahren **meiner Großeltern** sind auch meine Vorfahren.

Der Unterschied ist nur, dass in den zuvor genannten Beispielen kein Personalpronomen (»mein«) verwendet wird, sondern bestimmte und unbestimmte Zahlwörter (jeder, alle, beiderlei, jeglicher).

Diese Zahlwörter sind selbst aber Attribute des nachfolgenden Wortes, und müssen daher mit dem jeweiligen nachfolgenden Wort in Numerus (Einzahl oder Mehrzahl) Kasus (Grammatischer Fall) und Genus (grammatisches Geschlecht) übereinstimmen.

Das Wort »jeglicher« kann nicht im Plural verwendet werden. Man kann es auch durch »jeder einzelne« ersetzen:

> Menschen jeden einzelnen Geschlechts ...

Da im Singular das Pronomen dasselbe Geschlecht wie das Nomen haben muss auf das es sich bezieht, kann es auch in allen drei Geschlechtern vorkommen:

> Männlich: Der Beruf.
>   Menschen **jeglichen Berufs** sind zu der Veranstaltung gekommen.
>
> Weiblich: Die Hautfarbe.
>   Menschen **jeglicher Hautfarbe** sind zu der Veranstaltung gekommen.
>
> Sächlich: Das Alter.
>   Menschen **jeglichen Alters** sind zu der Veranstaltung gekommen.

Die gesamte Deklinationstabelle für »jeglicher« kann man z.B. bei [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/jeglicher) nachlesen. Da die Beifügung in der nachgefragten Konstruktion im Genitiv stehen muss, ist für diese Konstruktion auch nur die Genitiv-Zeile von Interesse.

»Jegliche« passt aus zweierlei Gründen nicht:

- »jegliche« ist eine weibliche Form. *Das* Geschlecht ist aber sächlich.
- »jegliche« ist eine Form die im Nominativ oder im Akkusativ verwendet wird. Die geschilderte Konstruktion verlangt aber den Genitiv.

Answer (score 1):

Wenn Du [die Formen von *jeglicher*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/jeglicher) nachschlägst, siehst Du, dass *jegliche* nur im Femininum vorkommt. Da [Geschlecht](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Geschlecht) ein Neutrum ist, kann dies nicht die richtige Form sein. Du siehst dann, dass *jeglichen* im Neutrum nur Genitiv sein kann. Das ist es also. Man könnte auch sagen:

> von jeglichem Geschlecht.